# Medium Consultation For Gentiles

Tags: gentiles, avodah-zarah, noachide-laws, sorcery-magic-kishuf, sheidim-demons

Are gentiles allowed to consult mediums or talk to spirits?

The prohibition of witchcraft and the like is not explicitly mentioned in the Noahide laws as far as I'm aware, but I could see it going against the prohibition on idolatry or blasphemy.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the gentiles were driven out of Israel for performing those deeds seems to indicate that it is forbidden to them

> דברים י"ח:י"ב
> (יב) כִּי⁠ תוֹעֲבַת י"י כׇּל⁠ עֹשֵׂה אֵלֶּה וּבִגְלַל הַתּוֹעֵבֹת הָאֵלֶּה י"י אֱלֹהֶיךָ מוֹרִישׁ אוֹתָם מִפָּנֶיךָ.
> For whoever does these things is an abomination to Hashem. And because of these abominations Hashem your God drives them out from before you

See Aderes Eliyahu ad loc:

> מכאן שמוזהרים הכנענים על זה שאין עונשין אלא א״כ מזהירין.
>
> From here it is apparent that the Canaanites are warned regarding these deeds as there is no punishment without command.

@Meir points out that the above is actually R Yosei's argument in bSanhedrin 56b.

However, from Rambam's omission of them he seems to allow for them.

Meiri ad loc actually spells it out unambiguously:

> וכן חקות הגוים, כגון קוסם ומעונן ומנחש ומכשף וחובר חבר ושואל אוב וידעוני ודורש אל המתים, אף על פי שהם חקות הגוים ונמשכים הם לעיקרי עבודה זרה, מותרים הם בכולם. ואף על פי שנאמר בהם: 'בגלל התועבות ההם ה' מוריש אותם', ואם כן למה נענשו אחר שלא הוזהרו? לא אמרה אלא שהם סולם ומבוא לעניני עבודות זרות שעליהן נענשו

So, simple meaning of the Torah notwithstanding, it does indeed seem to be permissible for non Jews and are not subsumed under the rubric of avodah zarah despite their close relationship to each other.

Comment: The land vomits out unholiness. So it may be permitted _for them_, but they were driven out because it is unholy _for the land_? Or perhaps the equivalent way to say it is maybe it's only forbidden for them to do it in Eretz Yisrael

Comment: @RabbiKaii Netziv ad loc seems to read it like you. I went with the Vilna Gaon on this one as כִּי⁠ תוֹעֲבַת י"י כׇּל⁠ עֹשֵׂה אֵלֶּה seems to indicate that it is forbidden irrespective of loc

Comment: Rabbi Yosei makes this point in Sanhedrin 56b. However, in the Rambam's formulation of these halachos (Hil. Melachim chs. 9-10) he makes no mention of this, so at least according to him the halachah doesn't follow that opinion, and they are permitted kishuf.

Comment: @Meir Interesting. Aderes Eliyahu seemingly sides with R Yosei. I hear your deduction from Rambam. I see that Meiri makes the point explicit and reinterprets the verse as saying that these led to the a"z that they were punished for. https://www.sefaria.org/Meiri_on_Sanhedrin.56b.1?lang=bi&with=all